# Expandable list collapse hiding div elements (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've working on a website you can temporarily find [here](http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html). You'll notice that if you click any of the expandable elements it works perfectly, however when pressing the "collapse all" button the div elements holding the upvote and downvote images disappear from all list items and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong (I'm a jQuery n00b!), js code is as follows:

```
/* Full list expansion functionality */
$('#expandList')
.unbind('click')
.click( function() {
    $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
    $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
})
/* Full list collapse functionality */
$('#collapseList')
.unbind('click')
.click( function() {
    $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
    $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) without a selector selects *all* children, including the `<div>`s with the votes.

In your toggle script for the single items, you are using

```
$(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
```

Comment: is there a children() selector that can exclude certain div id's?

Comment: Afaik, you can use any filter selector with `children`. So `:not(#certain, #ids)` is possible (though I guess you want to use classes)

Comment: (You should quote that selector string though.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
```

This line of code finds all children in this element and hide them, so it includes your div's

Look at the HTML

```
<ul id="expList">
 <li class="collapsed expanded">
       <div id="upvoted" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#"><img src="img/votes/upvote.png" alt="upvote" width="14" height="14"></a></div>
      <div id="downvoted" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#"><img src="img/votes/downvote.png" alt="downvote" width="14" height="14"></a></div> | SNOW KAYAKING
  //You want to hide only this                      
  <ul style="display: block;">

  </ul>
</li>
```

Look at your code

```
 /* Full list collapsion functionality */
    $('#collapseList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click( function() {
        $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
    })
```

You can change your code to select only the `UL` element and hide it:

```
$('.collapsed ul').hide('medium');
```

OR

```
$('.collapsed').children().not("#upvoted,#downvoted").hide('medium');
```